# How does Loki "transport" to speak with The Other?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers, the-avengers-2012

In the Avengers, there is a scene where Erik is working on the device and Loki goes into a type of meditation.  Soon the area surrounding him dissipates and he is brought to Thanos's throne area (although we don't know Thanos is involved yet prior to the ending).  How is it that he can do this?  I know he can move about other places that contain shards of the Bifrost, but this doesn't seem to be that kind of "path".

Part of me thinks he uses the Mind Stone, since you can kind of see him "inhale" or meld with it prior to speaking to The Other.  But I thought the Mind Stone would be used more for manipulation of others, as he uses it throughout the movie pretty frequently.  So how does this transporation to see the Other occur?

Comment: It can be argued that he wasn't even transporting, but rather "projecting". See also [Thaddeus' answer here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/53519/21267) for details of Loki's abilities.

Comment: My assumption was what you said in your question: I thought it was a telepathic conversation.  It makes sense for the Mind Stone to allow a form of telepathy, and being an Infinity Stone, it makes sense for that telepathy to have quite an impressive range.  The way he's holding the staff seems oddly conspicuous, if it's just a power he has innately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the MCU Wiki, the Mind Stone has the power to "project the user's consciousness to a higher plane of existence".[image]

This is what is taking place when Loki and The Other converse during that scene. Loki is not actually "transporting" anywhere, but projecting his consciousness via the Mind Stone.

Comment: is that canon, or is that just some random user typing "here's what I saw in the movie" on a public Wikia?