# How did Loki touch Mjolnir in Thor (2011)?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, loki, thor-2011

In *Thor* (2011), after Thor is captured by SHIELD and Loki pays him a visit, Loki tries to lift Mjolnir (and fails).

However, it is clear Loki is not actually there. He appears out of nowhere and disappears into thin air, which are things he is not capable of doing. What he is capable of is creating a projection of himself - but such projections cannot touch anything, let alone show him whether or not he is capable of lifting Mjolnir.

So, what's going on here?

Comment: "*When Loki left his brother, he did not return to Asgard. Instead he visited another realm. The last time he had been here, he had fought at Thor’s side against the overwhelming numbers of the Jotun enemy.*" - Novelisation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Loki is physically there. He's travelled to Earth to speak to Thor (by commanding Heimdall to transport him by Bifrost), noting that his next stop is to go visit Laufey on Jotunheim, then return (again, by Bifrost) to Asgard.

He does, however, use his magic to conceal himself as he moves around the compound.

> 90 EXT. CRATER - NIGHT 90
>
> Agents and Scientists work to repair the damaged area around Mjolnir. They take no notice of Loki as he steps up beside the hammer. He stares at it -- intrigued, wondering. Can he do it?
>
> He reaches down, tries to lift it -- but can't. He lets it go, eyes it with contempt, then steps away. He gestures with his arms. An odd GREEN AND GOLD LIGHT rises from the ground, enveloping him, then he disappears.
>
> <sub><sup>[Thor: Screenplay](https://imsdb.com/scripts/Thor.html)</sup></sub>

Comment: Thank you, that's great. Not really clear by the film, to be honest, but it also doesn't really matter.

Comment: @Wade - Well, we know that Loki is definitively on Jotunheim because Lauffey picks him up by the throat and that he's on Earth because he tries to pick up the hammer.

Comment: Good point. But wait, Lauffey picks him up by the throat? It did not happen in the version I saw... Are you sure about this?

Comment: @Wade - The scene was in an earlier version of the script, but made it into the novelisation "*But Laufey was in no mood for any humor. “My men are dead, and I have no Casket,” he said. “You are a deceiver.” Loki had heard that before. Laufey reached out and seized Loki around the throat. Loki did not resist. This, too, had been part of his plan.*"

Comment: Thank you! That's very interesting, maybe I should get this book... Is it any good?

Comment: @Wade - It's a very short junior reader. You can borrow it online (for free) from Archive.org; https://archive.org/details/thorjuniornovel00eliz